# Shows tons of vlc application even after removing it

Tags: 16.04, vlc

I have removed VLC software but is still showing on my laptop. I have attached a screenshot:

[image: vlc screenshot]

I have tried almost every solution but could not clear VLC completely. I am using ubuntu 16.04.

What should I do to delete all vlc completely also its cache?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do we see in the screenshot? How did you produce it? Is it a directory listing, or a list of applications?

Comment: It is the screenshot taken while choosing the option 'open with' to play video.

Comment: Look in `.config/mimeapps.list` if there are many lines with "VLC" in them. If so, delete them.

Comment: sorry it did not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check in ~/.local/share/applications/ and delete all files that seem related to the applications involved.

Comment: oh yes it really worked. I deleted wine folder and its cache.